# A limit concerning the integral of $x^n$

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms

I pondered if the general integral of $x^n$ could be used with limits to prove that $$\int x^{-1}dx=\ln(x)+C$$

I started with $$\int x^ndx=\frac1{n+1}x^{n+1}+C$$

Then, I took the limit as $n$ approached $-1$.

$$\lim_{n\to-1}\frac1{n+1}x^{n+1}+C$$

[From graphing](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wb8j88zrks), I found that it was true, and that $C$ was something that tended towards $\infty$ in $\ln(x)=\frac1{n+1}x^{n+1}+C$

I also found from graphing, that $C$ may be found as a function of $n$:

$$C=-\frac1{n+1}$$

Or,

$$\ln(x)=\lim_{n\to-1}\frac1{n+1}x^{n+1}-\frac1{n+1}$$

I was wondering if there were a more direct way of proving the limit than this.

Comment: Knowing a priori that $\int\limits_1^x t^{-1}dt = \ln(x) - \ln(1) = \ln(x)$ might provide an integral to try and start with.

Comment: @Jared so you are suggesting we start with $\int_1^xt^ndt$?

Comment: Well, ideally, you don't know the final result, so you wouldn't know _where_ to start.  Certainly we want to integrate two positive factors (or two negatives)--we definitely don't want to cross $0$ if we intend to integrate negative exponents.  I'm merely saying that, because we _know_ the result, we can choose an integral that will work out nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Shifting $n$,
$$ \lim_{n\to-1}\left(\frac1{n+1}x^{n+1}-\frac1{n+1}\right) = \lim_{n \to 0} \frac{x^n - 1}{n} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{x^h - x^0}{h} = \left. \frac{d}{dy} x^y \right|_{y = 0}
$$
The right side is well known to be $\log x$ and a commonly used trick in integration. To prove it,
$$ \left. \frac{d}{dy} x^y \right|_{y = 0} = \left. \frac{d}{dy} e^{y \log x} \right|_{y = 0} = \left. \log x e^{y \log x} \right|_{y = 0} = \log x
$$

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

$$
\int\limits_1^x t^{n - 1}dt = \frac{x^{n} - 1}{n}
$$

We wish to take the limit as $n\rightarrow 0$:

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow 0} \int\limits_1^x t^{n - 1}dt = \lim_{n\rightarrow 0} \frac{x^n - 1}{n}
$$

You can certainly use L'Hospital's rule but I suspect it's somewhat circular to do so.  It requires knowing that $\frac{d}{dt}e^t = e^t$.  For $x > 1$ it's certainly the case that $x^n = e^{\ln(x)n}$.  This then gives, using L'Hospital's rule:

\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow 0} \frac{e^{\ln(x)n} - 1}{n} =&\ \lim_{n\rightarrow 0}\frac{\ln(x)x^n}{1}\\
=&\ \ln(x)
\end{align}

Comment: Yup. I submitted this sane answer to an earlier, identical question. This one should have been flagged as duplicate.

Comment: @martycohen Don't mind if you could find that question.

Comment: Found it - almost 3 years ago: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366563/how-to-integrate-1-x/366686#366686